# Multiple Streams in Trident Topology

Tags: apache-kafka, trident, apache-storm

I have multiple OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout reading from different Kafka topics. I want data from all these streams to go through  same set of Functions. What is the best way to achieve that. 
Do I need to create separate streams and pass each Tuple to same set of functions again. Like below?

```
BrokerHosts zk = new ZkHosts(getZooKeeperHosts());
TridentKafkaConfig spoutConf = new TridentKafkaConfig(zk, "Test");
spoutConf.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
TridentKafkaConfig spoutConf1 = new TridentKafkaConfig(zk, "Test1");
spoutConf1.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout kafkaSpout1 = new OpaqueTridentKafkaSpout(spoutConf1);

topology.newStream("event", kafkaSpout).each(new Fields("document"), new ExtractDocumentInfo(), new Fields("id", "index", "type"));
topology.newStream("event1", kafkaSpout1).each(new Fields("document"), new ExtractDocumentInfo(), new Fields("id", "index", "type"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the streams together, but any failure will cause both spouts to replay the batch.